# Microsoft SEAL : Subtraction of two PolyCRT composed ciphertext results in overflow

Tags: seal

Suppose I have two arrays **x = [1,2,3,4,5]** and **xMean = [3,3,3,3,3]**. I composed and encrypted the two array using PolyCRTBuilder ( xCiphertext and xMeanCiphertext ) . If I subtract the two ciphertexts ( xCiphertext MINUS xMeanCiphertext ), I should get  **xResult = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]** but after the homomorphic subtraction I am getting **xResultDecrypted = [40959, 40960, 0 ,1, 2]** . I can relate the overflow result to the plain modulus set but is there a work around for this problem. Here is the code:

```
int main()  {

    EncryptionParameters parms;
    parms.set_poly_modulus("1x^4096 + 1");
    parms.set_coeff_modulus(coeff_modulus_128(4096));
    parms.set_plain_modulus(40961);

    SEALContext context(parms);

    KeyGenerator keygen(context);
    auto public_key = keygen.public_key();
    auto secret_key = keygen.secret_key();

    Encryptor encryptor(context, public_key);
    Evaluator evaluator(context);
    Decryptor decryptor(context, secret_key);

    PolyCRTBuilder crtbuilder(context);

    int slot_count = crtbuilder.slot_count();
    int row_size = slot_count / 2;

    vector<uint64_t> x_pod_matrix(slot_count, 0);
    x_pod_matrix[0] = 1;
    x_pod_matrix[1] = 2;
    x_pod_matrix[2] = 3;
    x_pod_matrix[3] = 4;
    x_pod_matrix[4] = 5;

    Plaintext x_plain_matrix;
    crtbuilder.compose(x_pod_matrix, x_plain_matrix);

    Ciphertext x_encrypted_matrix;

    encryptor.encrypt(x_plain_matrix, x_encrypted_matrix);

    vector<uint64_t> x_mean_pod_matrix(slot_count, 0);
    x_mean_pod_matrix[0] = 3;
    x_mean_pod_matrix[1] = 3;
    x_mean_pod_matrix[2] = 3;
    x_mean_pod_matrix[3] = 3;
    x_mean_pod_matrix[4] = 3;

    Plaintext x_mean_plain_matrix;
    crtbuilder.compose(x_mean_pod_matrix, x_mean_plain_matrix);

    Ciphertext x_mean_encrypted_matrix;

    encryptor.encrypt(x_mean_plain_matrix, x_mean_encrypted_matrix);

    evaluator.sub_plain(x_encrypted_matrix, x_mean_encrypted_matrix);

    // Decrypt x_encrypted_matrix
    Plaintext x_plain_result;

    decryptor.decrypt(x_encrypted_matrix, x_plain_result);

    vector<uint64_t> pod_result;

    crtbuilder.decompose(x_plain_result, pod_result);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  {

        std::cout << pod_result[i] << '\n';

    }

    /*
    Expected output:
    -2
    -1
     0
     1
     2  
    */

    /*
     Actual output:
     40959
     40960
     0
     1
     2
    */


  return 0;

}
```

evaluator.negate() isn't going to help solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, the result you get is correct because the plaintext is only defined modulo `plain_modulus`. There is an overload of `PolyCRTBuilder::decompose` that takes a vector of `std::int64_t` and will automatically do the conversion you are hoping to see.